# Single SOQL query to list ALL Products with ALL Quote Line Items and ALL Order Products?

Tags: soql, product, quotelineitem, orderitem

While both Quote Line Item and Order Product have a lookup fields to Product, no relationship name is shown in Workbench.

Further digging indicates a somewhat hidden PriceBookEntry object exists in between.

OK, but since we can't query down more than one level, is there any easy way to make a single SOQL query to list ALL Products with ALL Quote Line Items & ALL Order Products?

It seems like it would be a basic thing, but I am stumped. Schoolboy error?

For example - the following simply does not work, even though there are lookup fields from both OrderItem and QuoteLineItem to Product:

```
Select id, (Select id from OrderItems), (Select id from QuoteLineItems) FROM Product2
```

Comment: It's not an error on your end, there actually is no relationship name (at least for `OrderItem`). You can't pull everything with a single query.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I'm not crazy, and further testing indicates this is an intentional SF design decision to force the use of the intended price book entry / currency. 

But in this case it's not relevant and I just want a list of Quote Line Items /Order Products for an outside use case via - ideally one - API query. 

Any ideas on if this is possible and best way to achieve? 

Appreciate any thoughts as this is not my expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from Workbench, there are no relationshipNames for `Product2` to `OrderItem` and `Product2` to `QuoteLineItem`. Yet you can query from `Product2` to `PricebookEntry`

[image]

However, you can query from `PricebookEntry` to both `OrderItem` and `QuoteLineItem`

so you could do:

```
SELECT id, Product2.Name, (select Id from OrderItems), (select Id from QuoteLineItems) 
  FROM PricebookEntry
```

or

```
SELECT id, Product2.Name, (select id from OrderItems), (select id from QuoteLineItems) 
  FROM PricebookEntry 
  WHERE Product2.ProductCode IN ('foo','bar')
```

and you can add whatever lookup fields you need to get Order details or Quote details

If in a multicurrency org, add CurrencyIsoCode to the returned fields or include in Where clause to get a single currency. If in a multi-pricebook org , add `Pricebook2.Name` to returned fields or WHERE clause

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for taking the time to put this together and yes, that approach should work!